# How do I create an .msi installer with Visual Studio 2010 for a C# webservices project?

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-installer

In my project i want to run somesetup.msi.But in source base I have find only somesetup.vdproj
How to resolve this?

Comment: somesetup.msi *is the result of building* somesetup.vdproj; it is equivalent of the "exe" or "all" from a setup project ..

Answer (score 0):

When building a setup, you need to specify the primary output and build the setup project afterwards.

This can be used even for VS 2010: http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.de/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html